# How to refresh the FutureBuilder data and refresh a sibling widget?

Tags: flutter

Here is the link to the code https://github.com/orange1121/flutter_app.

The app has a home page. The body of the home page is from the item_list widget. The item_list widget has a FutureBuilder that takes data from an sqlite database, then outputs the data in a ListView.

The home page also has a button that links to an add_item page. How can I refresh the item_list widget when I perform action on the add_item page?